# inspect mySQL database

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a mySQL database on my Windows PC.  I'm pretty sure I've found the relevant files, namely the following:

```
formula.frm
formula.ibd
db.opt
```

What is the natural way to inspect, edit, and generally play with the contents of these files?

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: See the contents of the database.  I'm an SQL noob.

Comment: Use any mysql Gui tools or see from mysql shell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not view the binary database files directly. MySQL is a service that you connect to with a client and then perform SQL commands. You will need a client (such as MySQL Workbench) to work with the server.

MySQL Workbench is the GUI tool that allows you to connect to a MySQL database and perform actions on it including querying and creating/modifying the various parts of the database.

MySQL Workbench intro: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-intro.html

Getting started with MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/tutorial.html

There is also the command-line utility that is included when you install the server. It will be in the BIN folder of the MySQL install directory.

Command-line client info: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql.html

Answer (score 1):

Use a tool like [Mysql Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) to connect to the DB. You do nothing directly to the files. You connect to the service and use the DB.

Answer (score 1):

William, it sounds like your question is "how do I take mysql binary files and turn them into something usable on my machine?".  If that's the case, you'll want to first [install MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/) on your machine if you haven't already.  Then you might have a look [here](http://www.chriscalender.com/?p=28) for how to recreate a database from a .ibd file.